# What happens with the dynamic memory allocation, of a matrix with different size of columns on each line?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, memory, dynamic

I'm trying to create a matrix in C++, having a shape of a triangle like this :

n = number of lines;
If i input n = 4, for example, my matrix should look like this :
1
23
456
78910

I've managed to do the following code :

```
int n;
cout << "Introduceti n: ";
cin >> n;
int** a = new int*[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a[i] = new int[i+1];
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i+1; j++) {
        *(*(a + i) + j) = (i * i + i) / 2 + j +1;
    }
}


for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i+1; j++) {
        cout << *(*(a + i) + j) << "|";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

The question is : why can i access a[0][1] and it shows me a value, if i instructed my pointer to stop initializing at a[0][0] ?

Comment: First of all, for any pointer or array `a` and index `i`, the expression `*(a + i)` is *exactly* equal to `a[i]`. The latter is easier to read, write and understand. Especially if you have a jagged array like yours.

Comment: *why can i access a[0][1]* -- C++ doesn't stop you from doing bad things like this.  C++ is a powerful language, however with great power comes great responsibility.

Comment: Nothing in C++ stops you accessing memory you aren't supposed to. It's just your program has [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) if you do.

Comment: And uninitialized memory is uninitialized. It will have *indeterminate* contents and values, and using these values for *anything* leads to *undefined behavior*. C++ also don't have any bounds-checking, it's your responsibility to not go out of bounds.

Comment: Did you find anything here useful? It is good that you post feedback, for the benefit of the SO community.

Answer (score 0):

You can access memory, regardless of it being initialized or allocated.
It is up to you to code avoiding those likely unwanted events, or having mechanisms in place to detect them.

So,

**why can i access a[0][1]...**

As said above

**... and it shows me a value, ...**

Because every bit in memory has **some** value.

Try code below, and you will probably understand what you are doing.

The least memory you can take is by ensuring you have contiguous allocation. So you would rather allocate storage in a linear array for (n*(n+1)/2) ints (the size of your triangular matrix), and then simply define functions/macros for accessing element (i,j). It may take not more than 20 lines of code... if you want to work fail-safe, you can include a few checks for a couple more lines.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Introduceti n: ";
    cin >> n;
    int **a = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = new int[i + 1];
    }

    cout << "Size of int is " << sizeof(int) << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
            *(*(a + i) + j) = (i * i + i) / 2 + j + 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
            cout << *(*(a + i) + j) << "|";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "a[0][0] @" << &(a[0][0]) << "=" << a[0][0] << endl;
    cout << "a[0][1] @" << &(a[0][1]) << "=" << a[0][1] << endl;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I get it now, from all the comments in here. Just one more question: is my code more memory efficient, than initializing a 2D array with a[4][4], but only showing i+1 columns on each line ?

Comment: @AlexIvan - Memory allocation is in many respects implementation dependent. But for sure, the best you can do about that is ensuring you have contiguous allocation. So you would rather allocate storage for (n*(n+1)/2) ints (the size of your triangular matrix), and then simply define functions/macros for accessing element (i,j).
It may take not more than 20 lines of code... if you want to work fail-safe, you can include a few checks for a couple more lines.